# My Google Marker is not showing up in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hey I am trying to create a Google Map using Google's API. The marker is not showing up after I've entered the correct code. Can someone please help me to find out why is is not showing up? I have done some research and most of the issues are caused by problems with the location.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport"></meta>
<title>Eastern Missouri School District Map  - Google Fusion Tables</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body, #googft-mapCanvas {
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 300px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

.pac-container {
  font-family: Roboto;
}

#type-selector {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}

#type-selector label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
</style>

<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text"
placeholder="Enter your address here">
  <div id="googft-mapCanvas"></div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;v=3"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function initialize() {
    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
    var isMobile = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('android') > -1) ||
      (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|BlackBerry|Windows Phone|iemobile)/));
    if (isMobile) {
      var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
      viewport.setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');
    }

    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('googft-mapCanvas');
    mapDiv.style.width = isMobile ? '100%' : '1000px';
    mapDiv.style.height = isMobile ? '100%' : '300px';
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.64936217820852, -90.53628850000001),
      zoom: 9,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    });
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend-open'));
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend'));

    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      map: map,
      heatmap: { enabled: false },
      query: {
        select: "col26",
        from: "11Q0B7iRayT2JIOBl8_VRUmitimhX1W01byuFDnAv",
        where: ""
      },
      options: {
        styleId: 2,
        templateId: 2
      }
    });

    if (isMobile) {
      var legend = document.getElementById('googft-legend');
      var legendOpenButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-open');
      var legendCloseButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-close');
      legend.style.display = 'none';
      legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
      legendCloseButton.style.display = 'block';
      legendOpenButton.onclick = function() {
        legend.style.display = 'block';
        legendOpenButton.style.display = 'none';
      }
      legendCloseButton.onclick = function() {
        legend.style.display = 'none';
        legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
      }
    }
  }


  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('pac-input'));


            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: LatLng(38.64936217820852, -90.53628850000001),
        map: map,
        draggable:true,
        title: "Your New Home",

    });
    marker.setMap(map);

</script> 
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.  If I run your code, I get a javascript error `Uncaught ReferenceError: LatLng is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have a javascript error in your code: `Uncaught ReferenceError: LatLng is not defined`.  This:

```
position: LatLng(38.64936217820852, -90.53628850000001),
```

Should be:

```
position: google.maps.LatLng(38.64936217820852, -90.53628850000001),
```

Other comments:

1. You are including the API twice.  Don't do that, it can cause issues, combine all the desired parameters into the one call (`v=3&ibraries=places`, the sensor parameter is no longer required)
2. You need to initialize your marker inside the initialize function where the map is initialized
3. You need to initialize the SearchBox inside the initialize function where the map is initialized and which runs on the window load event so the DOM has been rendered (`document.getElementById('pac-input')` can't find that element until it has been attached to the DOM).

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/2c62soje/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
  var isMobile = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('android') > -1) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|BlackBerry|Windows Phone|iemobile)/));
  if (isMobile) {
    var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
    viewport.setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');
  }

  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('googft-mapCanvas');
  mapDiv.style.width = isMobile ? '100%' : '1000px';
  mapDiv.style.height = isMobile ? '100%' : '300px';
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.64936217820852, -90.53628850000001),
    zoom: 9,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  });
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend-open'));
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend'));

  layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    map: map,
    heatmap: {
      enabled: false
    },
    query: {
      select: "col26",
      from: "11Q0B7iRayT2JIOBl8_VRUmitimhX1W01byuFDnAv",
      where: ""
    },
    options: {
      styleId: 2,
      templateId: 2
    }
  });

  if (isMobile) {
    var legend = document.getElementById('googft-legend');
    var legendOpenButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-open');
    var legendCloseButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-close');
    legend.style.display = 'none';
    legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
    legendCloseButton.style.display = 'block';
    legendOpenButton.onclick = function() {
      legend.style.display = 'block';
      legendOpenButton.style.display = 'none';
    }
    legendCloseButton.onclick = function() {
      legend.style.display = 'none';
      legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('pac-input'));


  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.64936217820852, -90.53628850000001),
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    title: "Your New Home",

  });
  marker.setMap(map);
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#googft-mapCanvas {
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 300px;
}
#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}
.pac-container {
  font-family: Roboto;
}
#type-selector {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}
#type-selector label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places"></script>
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter your address here">
<div id="googft-mapCanvas"></div>
```

Comment: I am now trying to get the search box to work. I put this this code in the initialize function as you suggested but now no map is rendering.

Comment: `//place change event on search box
 google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed',function(){
  
  //console.log(searchBox.getPlaces());
  var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
  
  //bound
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var i, place;
  
  for(i=0; place=places{i};i++){
   console.log(place.geometry.location);
   
   bounds.extend(place.geometry.location); 
 
  }
  
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  map.setZoom(15)`

Comment: That is another question.